# How to cluster data where each sample has a different amount of different features?

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, binary-classification

I decompiled one million binaries and stored a representation of every function in a database. 
Each binary has a list of functions. 
Each function has a number of callees (how often its called by other functions) and callers (how often it calls other functions) as well as a list of functions it imports.
I want to create clusters based on the list of functions. 
Example of the data:

```
Binary A: {
    "functions": [
        {
            "id": "37",
            "num_callees": 2,
            "num_callers": 4,
            "imports": {
                "KERNEL32": [
                    "GetProcessHeap",
                    "HeapAlloc"
                 ]
        
        },
        {
             "id": "2873",
    ]        ...
}
```

Total functions: 147 million 
Unique function ids: 22 million

I looked into KModes clustering, but it seems that deals with categorical data where each sample has the same features. In my case, most binaries have 0 overlapping functions with another sample.
What method would be best to cluster this type of data?

The goal of this is to cluster binaries together which contain the most similar functions. In order to see patterns in malware families. Most of my data is malicious code.

Comment: Clustering finds similarities.  What similarities are you looking for? What is the problem you are trying to solve with clustering?

Comment: I am trying to find similarities in order to cluster malware binaries together to find patterns in malware families. Seeing which malicious files share the same functions should help to generate malware detection rules and give insight into the files.

Comment: Are you recording just the aggregate counts or the actual functions called? You could cluster based on *which* functions are called if you have that info, whereas clustering based on aggregate number called may not be as informative.

Comment: I am only storing the aggregate counts of the functions called. I know which functions are called and how often, but not which function is the caller.

Comment: I do not know anything about malware detection. Perhaps what you are looking for is intersections, not clustering. Or perhaps some similarity measurements. You can cluster and make this predictive, just need to organize the function names into features. I am no idea about the data if that will be too sparse to find the clusters you are looking for. Need to try it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Craig. I am doing that approach now just looking for intersections of the same functions.